# Image URL is not working while trying to use as background styling

Tags: javascript, css, api

I'm getting this image link dynamically from an Api and i'm trying to use the image url as the backgroungImage style of the page.

the URL looks like this : `/ezXodpP429qK0Av89pVNlaXWJkQ.jpg`

```
export default class View {
    constructor() {
        this.info = document.getElementById('header');
        this.backImage = document.getElementById('top');
    }

    showBack(img) {
        this.backImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;

        this.img.innerHTML = `<div class="bottom" id="bottom">
       <img src="${img}" alt="">
        </div>
        `
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this error

> GET http://localhost:8080/ezXodpP429qK0Av89pVNlaXWJkQ.jpg 404 (Not Found)

I've used this similar technique with other URLs before but this one isn't working.

Comment: The error is straightforward. Where exactly is the image? Is it inside some `content/images` folder inside your project?

Comment: I'm getting the image from an external api , this endpoint https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=api_key&language=en-US&query=jack%20reacher&page=1&include_adult=false   and extracting the image url and passing it as `url(${img})`

Comment: The error says you don't have that file in your local directory and rightly so. You should append the image with the some base URL of the website you are getting it from.

Comment: Tried with some base urls still no luck :(          
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see that API is providing you relative url of the image placed on API server or alike. So you need to get the absolute url of the image. E.g consider google image url https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png. You are getting url part '/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'. As image is located at google server you need to prepend 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/' portion while using this image in your web page.